# MSMQ console showing message count but no messages for private queue

Tags: msmq

I have a transactional private message queue (among other message queues on which I have not seen this problem) on a Windows Server 2008 R2 server.

This particular queue has a recurring problem happening every few weeks where the console shows a nonzero count of messages in the queue, but it does not have any messages in the queue itself or any subqueue.  Queue Explorer shows the same thing.  Performance counters indicate there are messages like the count in the built-in msmq console and queue explorer.

I cannot find any messages.  I understand that I could see a situation like this for outgoing queues with dead letter tracking such that it may have been delivered to a remote machine but not yet processed.  This is not an outgoing queue, though.  Messages are sourced from remote machines and have landed here on this machine.

Also, I am certain that the count I'm seeing are not journal messages or subqueues.

Does this make any sense?  Is there a logical explanation for this and under some circumstance this is expected?  If so, what is it?

EDIT: Removed info about purging queue removing the count - that was incorrect.  Purging actually does nothing and leaves me in the same state as before with a count reflected, but no messages showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, you can see a message count on an outgoing queue if source journaling is in use. The invisible messages are there in case they need to be moved to the DLQ.

I would expect your problem to be similar - there should be a visible message in the outgoing queue and an invisible message in the destination queue because delivery hasn't completed. I assume a handshaking or storage acknowledgement has been lost along the way. Or maybe the message has been processed and removed from the queue but MSMQ couldn't update the sender of the fact.

Check the outgoing queues on the remote machines sending TO this queue.

Comment: thanks john, that's good insight.  looking into it to see what i can determine.  will report back.

Comment: there are multiple clients that send messages to this queue server.  is there an easy way i can see which one(s) might be having/causing communication problems to narrow the field of what i am looking for?

Comment: i see nonzero counts in outgoing queues, but also see no messages in those.  i have the same number for number of messages and unacknowledged.

Comment: it seems some of the messages are getting through and getting processed - they are from some of the sending machines.  it's those from a subset of the sending machines that are having a problem.  i can't seem to find a commonality.  all machines are on the same domain (but using private queues, such that domain shouldn't be an issue with public queues), everyone and anonymous login have full control.  any ideas how i can figure out what is causing this?

Comment: If you are confident that 100% of data messages are delivered and processed then you are losing acknowledgement messages. Use of domain, private queues, anonymous logon has no impact on this. Solving this will require monitoring of packets on the wire to see where they are being lost. Troubleshooting multiple senders is going to be long and tedious.

Comment: still haven't gotten to the bottom of this, but deciding it's not worth pursuing further - using a different machine and not having these problems there.  thanks for your help.

Comment: This shouldn't be marked as answered if it didn't solve the problem. I ran into a similar issue and it turned out I was trying to reuse the same queue. The two readers expected different message formats and so an `UnknownMessageReceived` event was being raised by WCF (`ServiceHost`). Long story short, create a separate queue for each service contract. I was seeing the message sort of disappear for 10 minutes at a time. All I could see was the count of 1 in the console that whole time. Randomly the message would end up getting processed. But the delay was insane.